# Get object type on runtime PRISM MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm trying to create a PRISM app that uses modules and views loaded On-Demand. When I load views and modules as "WhenAvailable" everything works, but that's not what I want.

```
    void Navigate(object obj)
    {
        if (obj != null)
        {
            PreloadView(obj as IView, "ContentRegion");
            _manager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", obj.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void PreloadView<T>(T obj, string regionName) where T : IView
    {
        var region = _manager.Regions[regionName];
        var viewName = obj.ToString();

        var view = region.GetView(viewName);
        if (view == null)
        {
            view = _container.Resolve<T>();
            region.Add(view, viewName);
        }
        _manager.Regions[regionName].Activate(view);
    }
```

Here's my code that's loading view, located in MainWindowViewModel class which handles regions and nothing else. I would work if only I could somehow get the real object type on Navigate function. It's always **System.RuntimeType** even though it says in debugger that it's a **UserControl** which implements **IView**. I can't get my head around this to work.
I know that this method works because when i put **UserControl** explicitly instead of **T** everything loads properly. But I have multiple views in my app, and new to come, so doing this non-generically is kind of not an option.
Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: What version of Prism are you trying this with?

Comment: @R.Richards I believe it's the newest version, got it from nuget 2 weeks ago, its **6.2.0.0**

Comment: Your code in combination with your comments makes no sense to me.  In order to load modules on demand, you have to use the module manager.  Also if you are manually adding views to the region, you don't have to give them a name. Just create the view and stick it in the region.

Comment: @BrianLagunas Honestly, I was using pluralsight course for PRISM (wasn't that yours by the way?) I was having problem with a view returning **System.Object** when module was ondemand. How do I go around loading modules on demand, when I want to load a view that's inside a module?

Comment: When a module is loaded on Demand, that means you either have to load it manually, or a module that depends on it loads it for you. Either way, you can't access a module that hasn't been loaded into the app domain.

Comment: how do you invoke `Navigate`? Where do you get `system.RuntimeType`? in `obj.ToString()`?

Answer (score 0):

User **dynamic** keyword. It will accept the type at runtime.